# Searching exact phrase from google

Tags: python

I am trying to search some phrases from google search engine using python. I give input string `'DVD player'` and Google search for the pages with both words and formalize the search with `DVD+player` term. But I want to search exact phrase. I tried to replace the term with `"\"DVD plyar\""` so that the google will search the term as `"DVD player"`, but it doesn't seems to be working.

Following is the code picked from other questions.

```
import json    
import urllib.request    
def showsome(searchfor):    
    query = urllib.parse.urlencode({'q': searchfor})    
    url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s' % query

    search_response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)    
    search_results = search_response.read().decode('utf8')    
    results = json.loads(search_results)    
    data = results['responseData']    
    print ('Total results: %s' % data['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'])

    hits = data['results']    
    print ('Top %d hits:' % len(hits))    
    for h in hits: print (' ', h['url'])

    print ('For more results, see %s' % data['cursor']['moreResultsUrl'])    

showsome("\"DVD player\"")
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? If there is an error message please add it to your question, if not, please describe what you expected to happen and what actually happens. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for future questions.

Comment: Also, please *indent your code* correctly - it is much easier if code can be pasted from the question. Look at [Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to see how to do it (basically, just indent all your code by 4 extra spaces).

Comment: The code is running perfectly. For input 'DVD player' it search Google for all those pages where either 'DVD' is found or 'player' is found. But I want to search only for those pages where Google can find the complete phrase 'DVD player'. Usually at Google home page we have to write the phrase in inverted commas to search the exact match. I tried to add inverted commas as [showsome("\"DVD player\"")] but still it search for the both words independently rather than searching the whole phrase.