# Python Code to Retrieve Records of Exact Phrase/String for a Google Search Query

Tags: python, string, search, google-api-python-client, phrase

There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36397022/searching-exact-phrase-from-google) but it is not answered.

I am trying to retrieve a list of URL links for the EXACT phrase/string in a Google search query with python code. I do not want search results or URL links of SIMILAR phrases/strings. Hence, my list can contain nothing (or len[MyList] == 0) if there is no EXACT match for my search phrase/string in google search.

For example, the picture shows no result for a Google search for the string "Comparison technique to expose conversation dynamics in meta-analysis."

[image]

However, when I run the Python code below with the string "Comparison technique to expose conversation dynamics in meta-analysis." as search query it returns some results in the list and I don't want that. Please how can I modify the code so that only records of the EXACT phrase/string will be returned in the list?

For example, such that the search for the phrase "Comparison technique to expose conversation dynamics in meta-analysis." in ggogle will return an empty list `[]` as there is no EXACT matching result for the search query/phrase in google. Here is the code:

```
try:
    from googlesearch import search, quote_plus
except ImportError:
    print("No module named 'google' found")

query = "Comparison technique to expose conversation dynamics in meta-analysis."

result = []

for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=1, stop=2, pause=2):
    result.append(j)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to use Google dorks `intext:"your_search"` into your query. The purpose of this functionnality is to search only this strict sentence in websites text. To accomplish that, you only need to include the double quote character (`%22` is the url encoded correspondance) in your query :

```
try:
    from googlesearch import search
except ImportError:
    print("No module named 'google' found")

query = 'intext:%22Comparison technique to expose conversation dynamics in meta-analysis.%22'

result = []

for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=1, stop=2, pause=2):
    result.append(j)

print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly! I tried a different phrase search query with no result in google and the list returned empty. Just what I want. Thanks for your help I tried it for days and could not figure out what to do.